# "For" loop issue at ArrayList method in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have an issue at TestVolleyTeam.java. I cannot get the list arrays to work, I am honestly confused. I don't really know how to assign the lists with the "for" loop, I have probably made a mistake there.
The code is supposed to show the list of the players by using both the VolleyPlayer class and the VolleyTeam class through the TestVolleyTeam class. Can anyone spot the mistakes I've made?

```
class VolleyPlayer {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private int flnum;
   private int height;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getSurname() {
       return surname;
   }

   public int getFlnum() {
       return flnum;
   }

   public int getHeight() {
       return height;
   }

   public VolleyPlayer(String n, String sur, int fl, int h) {
       name = n;
       surname = sur;
       flnum = fl;
       height = h;
   }

   public VolleyPlayer(String n, String sur, int fl) {
       this(n, sur, fl, 185);
   }

   public VolleyPlayer(String n, String sur) {
       this(n, sur, 3);
   }

   public VolleyPlayer(String n) {
       this(n, "Brown");
   }
}





import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VolleyTeam {
   private String teamname;
   private String city;
   private int year;
   private ArrayList<VolleyPlayer> players;

   public String getTeamname() {
       return teamname;
   }

   public String getCity() {
       return city;
   }

   public int getYear() {
       return year;
   }

   public ArrayList<VolleyPlayer> getPlayers() {
       return players;
   }


   public void setTeamname(String newTeamname) {
       this.teamname = teamname;
   }

   public void setCity(String newCity) {
       this.city = city;
   }

   public void setYear(int newYear) {
       this.year = year;
   }

   public void setPlayers(ArrayList<VolleyPlayer> newPlayers) {
       this.players = players;
   }
}  






import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestVolleyTeam {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       VolleyTeam myObj = new VolleyTeam();


       String teamname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the name of the team?", "Input");

       myObj.setTeamname(teamname);


       String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the city of the team?", "Input");

       myObj.setCity(city);


       String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the foundation year of the team?", 
                                                 "Input");
       int year = Integer.parseInt(input);
       myObj.setYear(year);


       myObj.getTeamname();
       myObj.getCity();
       myObj.getYear();


       VolleyPlayer first = new VolleyPlayer("Michael", "Scott", 1, 175);
       VolleyPlayer second = new VolleyPlayer("Jim", "Halpert", 2, 191);
       VolleyPlayer third = new VolleyPlayer("Dwight", "Schrute", 3, 189);
       VolleyPlayer fourth = new VolleyPlayer("Darryl", "Philbin", 4, 188);
       VolleyPlayer fifth = new VolleyPlayer("Andy", "Bernard", 5, 182);
       VolleyPlayer sixth = new VolleyPlayer("Oscar", "Martinez", 6, 173);
       VolleyPlayer seventh = new VolleyPlayer("Stanley", "Hudson", 7, 180);
       VolleyPlayer eighth = new VolleyPlayer("Kevin", "Malone", 8, 185);
       VolleyPlayer ninth = new VolleyPlayer("Creed", "Bratton", 9, 183);
       VolleyPlayer tenth = new VolleyPlayer("Toby", "Flederson", 10, 177);

       ArrayList<VolleyPlayer> vplist = new ArrayList<VolleyPlayer>();

       for (VolleyPlayer volleyPlayer : vplist) {
           vplist.add(volleyPlayer);
       }

       myObj.getPlayers();
       myObj.setPlayers(vplist);



       ArrayList<VolleyPlayer> vplist2 = volleyTeam.getPlayers();

       for (VolleyPlayer volleyPlayer : vplist2) {
           vplist2.add(volleyPlayer);

       }

       volleyTeam.getPlayers();
       volleyTeam.setPlayers(vplist2);

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, vplist2, teamname  + " " + city + ", "  + year, 
                                     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

   }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it breaks at the second 'for' loop

Answer (score 2):

The `List` is empty when you start, this code

```
for (VolleyPlayer volleyPlayer : vplist) {
```

is attempted to loop over an empty `List`. I think I see what you want, and it can be achieved with something like

```
List<VolleyPlayer> vplist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth));
```

Then you don't need a loop to add `first` - `tenth` to your `vplist`. Note I changed it the diamond operator `<>` on construction. And used `Arrays.asList` to add the elements.

Since you must use a `for` loop, create an inline array. Like,

```
for (VolleyPlayer volleyPlayer : new VolleyPlayer[] {
        first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh,
        eighth, ninth, tenth }) {
```

Comment: Note, these days, you can just write List<VolleyPlayer> vpList = List.of(first, second, ...);

Comment: I need to do it with a 'for' loop, it's a school assignment :(